# Extracting text from PDF : PDFLib vs PDF extract vs pdf2xml

Tags: java, php, pdf, text-extraction

I am looking for a library (if possible available in Java or PHP) in order to extract text from a PDF. There is a lot of software available, including:

- 3-Heights™ PDF Extract http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/pdf-extract-content-metadata-text.aspx
- PDFlib TET – Text Extraction Toolkit http://www.pdflib.com/products/tet/
- PDF2XML http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf2xml/

Which tools would you choose? What do you think of them?

Thank you very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favourite is iText (java) but extracting text from a PDF can be fraught with difficulties as the text in the PDF is not alway stored in the order in which it appears.

Answer (score -1):

itext had trouble properly extracting text from the irs i1040.pdf
as reported here:

<1> article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/65680

As near as I can figure out, when the fonts are embedded,
it's not always possible to get the right text extracted.
See:
  <2> www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201109/pdf-to-text-converter-cant-extract-text-which-render-by-embedded-fonts-2452.html
  <3> section 9.10.1 of:
      www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

<3> says:

If a font is not defined in one of these ways ... the characters
  cannot be converted to Unicode values without additional information.

I assume that "conversion to unicode values" is essential for text extraction.